# Reading Chrome cookies from command line

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, chromium

Is it possible to read "Cookies and Site data", from command line (programatically).

Chrome allows us to look at the "Cookies and Site data" by navigating to Settings-> Privacy Settings -> Cookies.

Is it possible to read that data through a command line script?

Comment: as mentioned in the answer, this does not qualify the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify which OS are you using. I found a script for OS X that claim doing what you want, give it a try: [Simple script to extract (encrypted) cookies out of Chrome OS X cookie store](https://gist.github.com/dacort/bd6a5116224c594b14db). If you are using Linux, you may need to dig in the script and make some changes for it to work with your distribution.